# Aero Snap is great, but are there any Windows 7 utilities to make windows snap to each other?

Tags: windows-7, aero-snap

I loves me some [Aero Snap](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/snap.aspx), but I'll admit to a little disappointment: when it was first announced, I pictured a feature by which the edges of non-maximized windows would 'snap' against each other when you moved them close enough together (either by dragging a window edge to resize the window, or by moving one window close to another by its title bar).

This would make it much easier to work with a bunch of windows side-by-side-by-side. Are there any third-party programs or utilities out there that do this?

Please note I'm not talking about products like [GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) that snap windows to a multi-paned grid, I'm talking about something that affects the behavior of window edges themselves.

**Update:** Moab's comment summed up what I'm looking for perfectly:

> More like docking windows to each other without modifying the size or placement?

Exactly.

Comment: You mean something like a tiling window manager ?

Comment: More like docking windows to each other without modifying the size or placement?

Comment: @Moab: Precisely correct.

Comment: Great idea, now if someone will code a program for us....call it Sticky Windows.

Comment: Display Fusion is a personal favorite of mine. It does window snapping, multi-monitor task bars, and all sorts of window/monitor management. The free version  includes window snapping feature.

Comment: The question could have been reformulated so it wasn't closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DisplayFusionPro](http://www.displayfusion.com/Download/) has an option that does both Application snaps and monitor snaps.  The program is designed mainly for mulitple monitors, but it also works for a single monitor.  I have the paid version, but there is a free version as well.  The free version however only allows for snapping to the monitor.

Comment: Barring the sudden revelation of a free alternative, I'm accepting this answer. :)

Comment: DisplayFusion Pro works great for this.  I have a couple of 24" monitors at work, and I have DisplayFusion Pro shortcut keys to snap a window to the exact right or left half of the screen.  Makes it easy to view two web pages at once, or folders or anything else I need.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of [allSnap](http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/) works in Windows 7 both 32 and 64 bit. It is reasonably configurable and should do exactly what you need.

As a bonus it's portable and tiny.

Comment: Heh, this question is so old that I've since switched entirely to OS X (not that it includes this feature, either...) :) But thanks for your input - after all, this question is hopefully useful to others beyond myself!

Comment: Too bad it doens't work properly in w8

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [WindowSpace](http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html) has this feature, as well. It's about the same price-point as DisplayFusion Pro, though.

Answer (score 1):

Somethig like this:

http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/

or

http://pitaschio.ara3.net/

?